Pi Kiosk webpage settings not saving
I am using a pi 4b to display a website. This site allows the user to sort/filter data in a preferred format. When I specify the sort/filter preferences in the UI, they are only saved for a short time. I have to reboot to get them back. They do not change and require reboot on the website if viewed on a Windows or Mac machine or tablet.
I have tried various versions of raspian, trying different browsers (chromium, Firefox) and cannot seem to solve it. I also tried kiosk mode or just showing the page full screen.

Maybe you can first check how these parameters are persisted.
Are those filters part of the URL, and maybe you refresh the page by clicking a URL which removes those?
You can also check Chrome's Developer tools by pressing F12, go to Application tab on the top and check session storage and cookies.
Once you know where they are stored, you can take further steps to investigate when they get lost (and why).
